Passing a function argument of the wrong type is allowed by MISRA?
I'm working on a bare-metal software on STM32H7 which is controled by a coding rules analyser (HELIX QAC) following MISRA-C 2012 standard.
The use case is the following:
   void function1(unsigned int i)
    {
        ...
    }
    
    
    void function2(void)
    {
        ...
        function1(1);
    }

The call to function1 is done with a signed integer but apparently there is no MISRA rule to forbid that. I know conversion from signed to unsigned is perfectly defined in C but it's still surprising because usually MISRA is very strict regarding implicit conversion (even if well defined in the C standard).
For example the following (not really a conversion by the way) returns an error:
unsigned long l = 0xFFFFFFFF;

because there is no U prefix (or explicit cast).
Is there a reason for that / a specificity in the C standard regarding function parameter implicit conversion ?

Not very familiar with MISRA, but I think constants can be implicitly converted in most contexts where other expressions cannot. Also I think you have some typos (function1 vs function2).

Perhaps MISRA doesn't forbid it because the compiler should complain that you pass an argument to a function that doesn't expect an argument? It's already forbidden by the language itself.

Or is the call function2(1) supposed to be function1(1)? In which case perhaps MISRA doesn't forbid it because it's all too common?

@Someprogrammerdude There is no ambuguity, 0xFFFFFFFF is not -1. It is the number 4294967295. If int cannot represent this value, then this constant has the smallest type that can.

Yes I corrrected a typo, it is obviously not my actual code

@Someprogrammerdude I think you were confused by the typo in my message, sorry

This implicit conversion has to do with MISRA 10.1 which has changed over different versions of MISRA standards.
In MISRA C 2004, rule 10.1 prohibited a larger subset of implicit casts, including this one. MISRA C 2012 relaxed this rule to allow implicit casts in more situations.

Is there a reason for that / a specificity in the C standard regarding function parameter implicit conversion ?

To preface, I only have access to MISRA C 2023 now and I couldn't find official justification for the change.
IMO, I suspect the rule was changed with the 2012 standard because the 2004 version of rule 10.1 resulted in a lot of explicit casts that may have made the code more difficult to read and only marginally safer. I'm basing that opinion on a few forum posts with confusion about 10.1 violations.

In particular, the "underlying type" of MISRA 2004 wasn't ideal because it enforced a cast after an implicit conversion had taken place.

In C, function parameter passing is done "as if by assignment" (C11 6.5.2.2). Therefore all rules about assignment also apply to function parameter passing. In this case all MISRA rules such as 10.1 about implicit conversions apply, as well as various rules about assignment.
Also 1 would be a MISRA rule violation because the intention is to use an unsigned type and so it must be 1u.
unsigned long l = 0xFFFFFFFF does involve a conversion from unsigned int to unsigned long on a 32/64 bit system. The rules about the default type for hex integer constants are rather intricate and poorly designed in the C language, giving you an int if the constant can fit in one, otherwise an unsigned int as in this case. So, 0x7FFFFFFF would be type int, 0xFFFFFFFF would be type unsigned int and 0x1FFFFFFFF will be signed long/long long. Leading to brittle code and the source of many bugs in embedded systems in particular. MISRA insists on u suffix so that we won't end up with arbitrary types, no matter if using decimal of hex constants.

"Also 1 would be a MISRA rule violation because the intention is to use an unsigned type and so it must be 1u."  there is no violation in mys analysis software if I do unsigned int = 1; But there is a violation if I do unsigned int = 0xFFFFFFFF; (int configured as 32 bits) because it expects a "U" after the 0xFFFFFFFF since it assumes it must be necessarily unsigned. Doesn't make sense for me. the violation concerns only the integer literal not the assignment

@GuillaumePetitjean If the intention is not to use negative numbers then it must be 1u. You only need to append the u/U suffix when the intention is to use positive numbers, which is most of the time.
